# foreach not grabing all records

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Controller, I have:

```
    $level1Navs = tblPages::where('pgeParent','=',0)->orderBy('pgeOrder','ASC')->orderBy('pgeTitle','ASC')->get();
    var_dump($level1Navs);
    foreach($level1Navs as $level1Nav) {
        $navbar = array();
        $navbar['pgeID'] = $level1Nav->pgeID;
        $navbar['pgeTitle'] = $level1Nav->pgeTitle;
        $navbar['pgeContent'] = $level1Nav->pgeContent;
        $navbar['pgeMainLevel'] = $level1Nav->pgeMainLevel;
        $navbar['level2'] = array();

        $level2Navs = tblPages::where('pgeParent','=',$level1Nav->pgeID)->where('pgeActive','=',1)->orderBy('pgeOrder','ASC')->orderBy('pgeTitle','ASC')->get();
        foreach($level2Navs as $level2Nav) {
            $navbar['level2']['pgeID'] = $level2Nav->pgeID;
            $navbar['level2']['pgeTitle'] = $level2Nav->pgeTitle;
            $navbar['level2']['pgeContent'] = $level2Nav->pgeContent;
            $navbar['level2']['pgeMainLevel'] = $level2Nav->pgeMainLevel;
            $navbar['level2']['level3'] = array();

            $level3Navs = tblPages::where('pgeParent', '=', $level2Nav->pgeID)->where('pgeActive', '=', 1)->orderBy('pgeOrder', 'ASC')->get();
            foreach ($level3Navs as $level3Nav) {
                $navbar['level2']['level3']['pgeID'] = $level3Nav->pgeID;
                $navbar['level2']['level3']['pgeTitle'] = $level3Nav->pgeTitle;
                $navbar['level2']['level3']['pgeContent'] = $level3Nav->pgeContent;
                $navbar['level2']['level3']['pgeMainLevel'] = $level3Nav->pgeMainLevel;

            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($navbar);
```

There are 9 items off the first level, but when it hits the var_dump, I only get this:

```
array (size=5)
  'pgeID' => string '10' (length=2)
  'pgeTitle' => string 'News' (length=4)
  'pgeContent' => string '0' (length=1)
  'pgeMainLevel' => string '10' (length=2)
  'level2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'pgeID' => string '50' (length=2)
      'pgeTitle' => string 'News Stories' (length=12)
      'pgeContent' => string '1' (length=1)
      'pgeMainLevel' => string '10' (length=2)
      'level3' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Its like its only running through each foreach one time.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example just keeps overwriting itself. Each iteration of the first array you are resetting the `$navbar['level2']` item. It overwrites itself because you call `$navbar['level2'] = array();` which takes everything you did in the 2nd and 3rd iteration and sets it back to a blank array.

You will have to build out your array by appending (pushing) to each nested array like:

```
$navbar['level2']['pgeID'][] = $level2Nav->pgeID;
```

Also check it the array exists before you instantiate an array like this:

```
if( is_array($navbar['level2']) === false ) {
    $navbar['level2'] = array();
}
```